# Regarding UNIX Shell Script

Tags: unix, shell

When there is no files inside the folder the below script goes inside the for loop. Not sure what i can modify so that it doesn't go inside the for loop. Also when there is no files inside the directory exit status should be success. Wrapper script checks the exit status of the below script

```
     FILESRAW ="/exp/test1/folder"  .
for fspec in "$FILESRAW"/* ; do
  echo "$fspec"
  if [[ -f ${fspec} ]] ; then
       ..... processing logic
  else
     ... processing logic
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if using bash,

you can set `nullglob`

`shopt-s nullglob`

if you have hidden files,

`shopt -s dotglob`

with ksh,

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -o noglob
for file in /path/*
do
  ....
done
```

Comment: I am using korn shell.  I dont want any hidden files also.   Do i need to put the above two lines in the begining of shell script

Comment: you set them before your script

Answer (score 0):

```
for fspec in `dir $FILESRAW` ; do
```

Answer (score 0):

To exit if $FILESRAW is empty:

`[ $( ls "$FILESRAW" | wc -l ) -eq 0 ] && exit 0`

If this test precedes the loop, it will prevent execution from reaching the for loop if $FILESRAW is empty.

When $FILESRAW is empty, "$FILESRAW"/* expands to "/exp/test1/folder/*", as ghostdog74 points out, you can change this behavior by setting nullglob with

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

If you want hidden files, set dotglob as well:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Alternately, you could use ls instead of globing. This has the advantage of working with very full directories (using a pipe, you won't reach the maximum argument limit):

```
ls "$FILESRAW" | while read file; do
     echo "$file"
```

This becomes messier if you want hidden files, since you'll need to exclude . and .. to emulate globing behavior:

```
ls -a "$FILESRAW" | egrep -v '^(\.|\.\.)$' | while read file; do
    echo "$file"
```

Comment: using just `ls` would leave out hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ksh,
try putting this in front of for loop so that it won't go inside it.
"**set -noglob**"
Even I have got the same problem, but I was able to resolve it by doing this.